# setting PORT and HOST manually for facebook/create-react-app production build

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

i used facebook/create-react-app to create a react application and successfully got production build running on http://localhost:5000.

my question is is there any way to change the 5000 PORT in this production build ?

according to the Advanced Configurations, there is no way to change HOST and PORT in production, only available for the development

> > > https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration.

this is my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "serve -s build"
  }
```

this is my .env

```
##
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=8008
## PUBLIC_URL=http://myexamplesite.lk/
##

REACT_APP_ROOT_BASE_URL=https://myexamplesite.lk/api/
REACT_APP_ROOT_BASE_URL_META=http://myexamplesite.lk/
```

Answer (score 2):

From [react docs:](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

"the port can be adjusted using the -p or --port flags."

```
serve -p 7000 -s build
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,  i done this like "deploy": "serve -p 8080 -s build", but i have to add this every time i changing the port or i have to declare like, "deploy:dev": "serve -p 8080 -s build", "deploy:qa": "serve -p 9090 -s build" for every environment, my concern is to set this using a .env file

Answer (score 2):

[create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used) listed all .env files which can used when run `npm run build`
To change PORT in local production build you can create a file name `.env.production.local` and set the PORT you want:

```
##
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=5000
## PUBLIC_URL=http://myexamplesite.lk/
##

REACT_APP_ROOT_BASE_URL=https://myexamplesite.lk/api/
REACT_APP_ROOT_BASE_URL_META=http://myexamplesite.lk/
```